# how many characters in \n JAVA?

Tags: java

just a quick question.

I wonder how many characters count for **\n** (new line ) in JAVA?

Because I need to fit 160 chars in one String,etc.

So.. How many chars should I consider for \n when appending to my StringBuffer?

Thanks

Comment: Pick the correct answer though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`'\n'` itself is one character when represented internally in Java, but when interfacing with external systems it can be represented by anywhere between 1 and 8 bytes. Some systems and protocols represent a newline with `\r\n`, which is 2 characters. And the encoding matters as well, since it can cause each character to use 1, 2, or 4 bytes.

Without more information on what system or protocol the characters are going to be sent on it is not possible to give a completely accurate answer.

Comment: Actually I plan to fit 160 char string buffer for one SMS. I am working on sending SMS. So I need to check whether it fit for one SMS or I have to send multiple SMSs.

Comment: Put it through the GSM 03.38 codec first, *then* check the length.

Answer (score 4):

The property `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is a system dependant new-line String.  This can be one or two characters. `\n` is the line feed (single) character which could happen to be the same as a new line, but this is platform dependant.

Comment: Deserves to be much higher on the list here.

Answer (score 3):

1 character.

```
String str = "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq\n";
System.out.println(str.length());
```

output 160

Answer (score 2):

'\n' is just a single character.

Answer (score 2):

\n should be single character only.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` in java corresponds to only one character. If you need to check then might this code will help.

```
String str = "\n";
char[]  test = str.toCharArray();
System.out.println(test.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

‘\n’, '\r', '\t', '\0' they are all one character in both java and c/c++, and other languages.